# Euclidean distance between two variables

Tags: java

I am attempting to pass a array or list of X Y Z variables into a method which calculates the Euclidean Distance.

Here is my method:

```
public static double calculateDistance(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    double distance = 0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
        distance += Math.pow(array1[i]-array2[i], 2.0);
        distance = Math.sqrt(distance);
    }
    return distance;
}
```

Here is my main code:

```
int b[] = {0, 0, 0};
int c[] = {10, 0, 0};
double distance = calculateDistance(b, c);
System.out.println(distance);
```

The output is: 1.7782794.. When it should be 10. Any ideas?

Comment: distance = Math.sqrt(distance); should only be called *after* the loop

Comment: Thank you! Thats so obvious, i was just stuck on it. Appreciate it!

Comment: Also you might want to harden this code a bit. If array1 is longer than array2, you'll get an index out of bounds in your loop once `i` is greater than array2's length.

Comment: One might wonder if x * x is more efficient than pow(x, 2). Turns out that the compiler converts pow(x, 2) to x*x (see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/a34b3268a14f/src/share/vm/opto/library_call.cpp)

Comment: You should consider upvoting and/or accepting answers you find useful here.

Answer (score 3):

`distance = Math.sqrt(distance)` is wrong:

```
public static double calculateDistance(double[] array1, double[] array2) {
    double Sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        Sum = Sum + Math.pow((array1[i] - array2[i]), 2.0);
    }

    return Math.sqrt(Sum);
}
```

Then

```
double b[]={0,0,0};
double c[]={10,0,0};
double distance = calculateDistance(b, c);
System.out.println(distance);
```